# Copy Stack Overflow code using Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey, tampermonkey, userscripts

What is an optimized way to copy Stack Overflow code fast and reliable using TamperMonkey?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a functional script that makes copying Stack Overflow code snippets faster. This script works as an add-on feature to Stack Overflow website. This script will make things easier for programmers like me.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Stack Code
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      1.1
// @description  Copy code snippets inside Stack Overflow website!
// @author       Youssof H.
// @match        https://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match        https://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match        https://*.superuser.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

var $ = window.jQuery; // basically to remove IDE warnings

var copyText; //Variable that holds code value
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("pre").before("<button class='copy_btn'>copy</button><br>"); //Add a button before every code snippet
    $(".copy_btn").click(function(){
        $(this).append('<textarea id="copytxt" style="font-size: 0px;contenteditable:false;background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" placeholder="Code to copy..."></textarea>'); //Make a textarea that will hold code for small instants
        copyText = $("#copytxt");
        var sel_code = $(this).nextAll("pre:eq(0)").find("code").text(); //Selects code
        copyText.val(sel_code); //Sets the value of the texarea
        copyCode(); //Run copying function
    });
});

function copyCode() {
    copyText.select(); //Select code in texarea
    document.execCommand("copy"); //Execute command copy text from selected input(textarea)
    copyText.remove(); //Delete textarea when finish
}
```

Add Tampermonkey extension to your browser then copy and paste that code into a new userscript. Once finished visit this page to test its functionality. A blue button should appear before every code snippet, once you click that button, it will copy the following content.

> **Note:** You have to refresh sites you visit when you make enhancements on your scripts!

I hope this helps you people. Any enhancements accepted.